# Access project classes from a maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, plugins, classpath, classloader

I'm making a maven plugin that run in test phase, in pom.xml configuration of a project that uses my plugin, I'm setting a class canonical name that I want to use to run that class from my plugin, basically I'm making a way to have a dynamic class loading of classes inside the project from my plugin.

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("... class from pom.xml ...")
```

When I run it I receive the expectable "ClassNotFoundException", seems the class loader are not the same or not shared.

There is a way to do it? Like capture the class loader from the project or receive it by dependency injection into my plugin? What is the best way?

Comment: Is the class that you are trying to load defined inside the plugin? If not, have you added the lib `<dependency>` containing this class in `<plugin>` definition in the pom?

Comment: @Antot I have included as a `<dependency>` in pom of the project, and also in a `<build>` to be used. But during the execution I want to load (or actually run it) from maven plugin.

Comment: Could you please share respective extracts of the `pom.xml` from the project and the plugin ?

Comment: @Antot Here is: https://gist.github.com/andrevlima/3cc1c06b94493bed177dc7ced3798942

Comment: I have similar requirement and I used this solution. Copied above getClassLoader() method in my mojo, injected MavenProject and calling the getClassLoader() using the class name defined in the pom.xml. Still it isn't working for me. I get ClassNotFoundException. Any idea what can be the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the Hibernate implementation in mojo can be used as a reference to make it:

Checkout the source code here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.mojo/hibernate3-maven-plugin/2.2/org/codehaus/mojo/hibernate3/HibernateExporterMojo.java#HibernateExporterMojo.getClassLoader%28%29

```java
    private ClassLoader getClassLoader(MavenProject project)
    {
        try
        {
            List classpathElements = project.getCompileClasspathElements();
            classpathElements.add( project.getBuild().getOutputDirectory() );
            classpathElements.add( project.getBuild().getTestOutputDirectory() );
            URL urls[] = new URL[classpathElements.size()];
            for ( int i = 0; i < classpathElements.size(); ++i )
            {
                urls[i] = new File( (String) classpathElements.get( i ) ).toURL();
            }
            return new URLClassLoader( urls, this.getClass().getClassLoader() );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            getLog().debug( "Couldn't get the classloader." );
            return this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        }
    }
```

To capture the "project" object, we can use the mojo dependency injection:

```java
/**
 * Dependency injected
 */
 @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}")
 public MavenProject project;
```

And use it to load some class in project class loader:

```java
getClassLoader(this.project).loadClass("com.somepackage.SomeClass")
```

Comment: I have similar requirement and I used this solution. Copied above getClassLoader() method in my mojo, injected MavenProject and calling the getClassLoader() using the class name defined in the pom.xml. Still it isn't working for me. I get ClassNotFoundException. Any idea what can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for this answer too. On [maven's Classloading guide page](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-maven-classloading.html) (it took me a while to find it, at the end of Plugin Classloaders section) it says:

> Please note that the plugin classloader does neither contain the
> dependencies of the current project nor its build output. Instead,
> plugins can query the project's compile, runtime and test class path
> from the MavenProject in combination with the mojo annotation
> requiresDependencyResolution from the Mojo API Specification. For
> instance, flagging a mojo with @requiresDependencyResolution runtime
> enables it to query the runtime class path of the current project from
> which it could create further classloaders.
>
> When a build plugin is executed, the thread's context classloader is
> set to the plugin classloader.

So from what i understand that text is, first you need to add `requiresDependencyResolution=ResolutionScope.RUNTIME`  on your @Mojo annotation, and then, write your custom classloader operation to access and load the neccessary classes on the project from your maven plugin.

```
@Mojo(requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.RUNTIME)
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {
//...
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", required = true, readonly = true)
private MavenProject project;

@Override
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    // Use the customLoader method to load a class
    Class<?> clazz = getClassLoader().loadClass("SOME_CLASS_NAME");
    
    // do whatever you want with the clazz, instantiate it, call its static methods, etc...
    //...
}

// Method courtesy from TabNine From Google Results.
private ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = null;
    try {
        List<String> classpathElements = project.getRuntimeClasspathElements();
        if (null == classpathElements) {
            return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        }
        URL[] urls = new URL[classpathElements.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < classpathElements.size(); ++i) {
            urls[i] = new File((String) classpathElements.get(i)).toURI().toURL();
        }
        classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls, getClass().getClassLoader());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return classLoader;
}
```

Some links:

- https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-maven-classloading.html
- https://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html
- https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject/getRuntimeClasspathElements
- [Maven mojo plugin to load class from hosting project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291857/maven-mojo-plugin-to-load-class-from-hosting-project?rq=3)
- [Load project class within maven mojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67703238/load-project-class-within-maven-mojo)