# Getting project classes in maven plugin

Tags: java, maven-plugin

I'm building a maven plugin that generates code and is part of the GENERATE_SOURCES phase. In order to generate the code I need access to the project's classes as well as the project's dependency classes.

I'm able to get the project dependencies by using MavenProject and creating a new ClassLoader similar to what [Access project classes from a maven plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737706/access-project-classes-from-a-maven-plugin) suggested. The problem is I also need access to the classes in the project not just classes in the dependencies of the project. Since the plugin is generating code it has to occur before the classes in the project are generated. Right now it works if I compile the project without the plugin and then compile the project with the plugin as the classes will be generated, but obviously this isn't a good solution. Is there anyway to create a ClassLoader that can access the classes before they are actually compiled or is there some technique I can use to generate the classes as a step in the plugin?